# Is it possible to have two stores sharing one backend and the same inventory?

Tags: multistore, inventory

I have two stores targeting different markets selling the same products.  I want to charge different prices on each site (high end and then budget) but I want them to share the same inventory so I can do stock control.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: stock qty states "global" I don't see why you couldn't share stocks between stores. Did you try?

Comment: I think till now u havent checked the magento manual. If you does it, you wont get this type of doubts...

Answer (score 3):

Yes! You can create two different stores in a single magento installation. Scope of *Price Attribute* in default ids *Website* level. You can change it to *Store View* level, if you want to use two different store views! And if you are using two different websites (not two different Store Views) then you can keep *Scope* of *Price* as *Website*.

Answer (score 2):

The stock Management in Magento is Global therefore you can have 2 stores with the same product and the shared stock.

You can read this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_config/edit/cataloginventory

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple websites in one Magento install. They can share the same products. Per magento-website you can set different prices, descriptions etc.